# How do I install Ubuntu on Windows 7 with BitLocker?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ntfs, wubi, bitlocker

I installed [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) 10.4 using [Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/) on a Windows 7 x64 on the first partion that is NTFS and it's using BitLocker and it does fail to load.

Is it Wubi incompatible with BitLocker or there is a way to configure the system without removing BitLocker and to make it work?

Currently when I try to load Ubuntu I get `No wbildr` error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: *You don't*. You cannot install Ubuntu using Wubi on a partition that is encrypted.